# IF ELSE statement within FOR IN loop is not working in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, for-loop

Hi guys Ive been trying to implement simple code that is changing the table data from null to not null. What i came up so far is this:

```
Declare
   mi number(2);
   ma number(2);
BEGIN
   SELECT MIN(ColumnA) INTO mi from TABLEA;
   select MAX(ColumnA) into ma  from TableA;
   FOR a in mi .. ma LOOP
     IF a = 3 THEN
       update TableA SET ColumnB = '0' WHERE ColumnB is null;
       execute immediate 'alter table TableA modify ColumnB not null';
     ELSE
       execute immediate 'alter table TableA modify ColumnB null';
     end if;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

The code seems to be working it go straight to the ELSE statement. The min value of columnA is 1 and the max value is 6.

I believe i am missing something in the if statement.

The logic behind this is that if ColumnA contain record 3 then the COLUMN B Should be modified to be not null.

Comment: what is the error ? it is giving error or ?

Comment: Your code looks fine. What is the data in the table? Can `a` > 3?

Comment: Currently TableA is set to null and the error is ORA_01451: column to be modified to NULL cannot be modified to null obviously.

Comment: Unrelated but you don't need two queries: `SELECT MIN(ColumnA),max(ColumnA) INTO mi, ma from TABLEA;` is much more efficient. Actually I don't think you even need the `FOR` loop -  a single `UPDATE` or `MERGE` will probably be enough.

Comment: @user3318414 Why *obviously* ? What is obvious to you is not obvious to everybody else, because we don't have your data. Please add sample input data to your post that exhibits the problem.

Comment: As i said in the previous column the Column curent type is null, so the code is executing after the else statement. which is execute immediate 'alter table TableA modify ColumnB null';

Comment: The logic behind this is that if ColumnA contain record 3 then the COLUMN B Should be modified to be not null.

Comment: The columns nullability is at the ddl level.  You need to decide whether you want nulls or not independent of the data values at a particular moment in time.  Look into a constraint or before insert row trigger.  Your dynamic ddl won't participate in  a transaction as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The loop goes through values 1 .. 6.

1: null
2: null
3: not null
4: null
5: null
6: null

So columnB gets set to "not null" but it gets set back to "null" directly afterwards.

Comment: I believe that IF a = 3 THEN is not working properly.

Comment: Hi thanks for this, I removed the else statement and the code is working. It is setting up the column to NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

**It is highly improbable that your code will ever work.**

Your code will work only if:

- There are no records in your table for which `columnA` = 3, and
- All the values for `columnB` is null for all the rows that exist.

Just think about what you have written:

- If there exists even one record where `columnA`=3, you are inserting
  a not null('0') value to `columnB`.

  The next time the loop runs( loop continues till a=6), a=4 this time,
  the control flows to `ELSE` part, and you are trying to modify this
  same column to `NOT NULL`. Didn't you yourself insert a '0'(`NOT NULL`) value to
  this column in the previous loop?
- If there is no record where `columnA`=3, then your control will always
  go to else part, so obviously if there is any existing record where
  `columnB` is not null, it will throw the same error